# Is there a way to prevent product duplicate recommendations when using Einstein?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, einstein, einstein-recommendations

We're using an Einstein Recommendations logicID to pull in 3 products. Example:

*Cat Product | Fish Product | Dog Product*

But sometimes, the same product recommendation will appear twice. Example:

*Cat Product | Fish Product | Cat Product*

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

**[EDIT]**

Just realized the image populated in the email does not match what the image URL redirects to when copied & pasted into the browser.

Reporting > Admin Tools > shows that Product Code , SKU ID, and unique ID all match.

Example:

1. https://1234567.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/logicID/l/1/%%emailaddr%%

leads to:

https://cat-img.png

2. https://1234567.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/logicID/l/3/%%emailaddr%%

leads to:

https://different-cat-img.png

**[EDIT]**
Solution:
Finally realized the correct product images display live in the inbox after sent. They are only incorrect when previewed in Content Builder. I guess this situation was a glitch.

Comment: a product can only be in a rec once, I'm guessing you have two similar products, can you provide the rec url?

Comment: I think you're onto something. I copied the image links. Both are initially the same, but one redirects to a different product. For some reason, Einstein is populating a different image in the email compared to what the actual image URL redirects to. Edited my post to include example URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the /i/ url from your recommendation this will provide your with the product code being recommended

`https://1234567.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/logicID/1/1/%%emailaddr%%`

returns:

`https://pi-templates.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/XXXXXXX/11965~1.png`

11965 is the product code. If you go to reporting >> admin tools you can search for this product code and review the ImageUrl for the item

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the image URL is showing the correct/matching product code based on your instructions. I also just realized that although the image is not correct when previewed in Content Builder, the correct image displays live in the inbox. So maybe this is just a glitch/false alarm?